# Get checked values from checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I have this check boxes that I need to get its checked values:

In this example, I would expect to get **Ubuntu**, because it is checked.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="my_label_3-4">
        <input id="my_label_3-4" type="checkbox" value="5" name="my_label_3[]" aria-invalid="false"></input>
        Windows 7, 8
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="my_label_3-5">
        <input id="my_label_3-5" type="checkbox" value="6" name="my_label_3[]" aria-invalid="false"></input>
        Mac OS
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="my_label_3-6">
        <input id="my_label_3-6" type="checkbox" checked="" value="7" name="my_label_3[]" aria-invalid="false"></input>
        Ubuntu                                  
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="my_label_3-7">
        <input id="my_label_3-7" type="checkbox" value="8" name="my_label_3[]" aria-invalid="false"></input>
        FreeBSD
    </label>
</div>
```

How do I do so?

This is what I did so far, but hasn't return any result:

```
echo 'checkbox';
foreach ($html->find('my_label_3') as $id) {
    echo $id; // returns 'checkbox'
}
```

Using Simple HTML Dom for parsing process

Comment: How we do know what `find` methods does? What is that?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention I'm using simple html dom to parse html

Comment: is this part of a form that gets submitted ? or are you parsing html you get from some place ?

Comment: Try `$html->find('my_label_3[checked]')` and `echo $id->value;`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli the latter

Comment: @barell still returns 'checkbox'

Comment: Note: Only checkboxes that are checked will actually show up after a submit operation.

Answer (score 1):

try using the `label` to identify the nodes, as **Ubuntu** is not the value of the `input`. It is the text of the `label`, the value of that `input` is 7.

```
foreach ($html->find('label[for^="my_label_3-"') as $label) {
    if (!empty($label.find('input[checked]'))){
        echo $label->innertext;
    }
}
```