# Php DOMDocument - is radio checked

Tags: php, dom

I'm parsing html using Php DOMDocument and iterating through all the elements to perform various replacements. When a radio button is detected how can I detect if it is checked, and if checked then replace with a character eg 'Y'; unchecked radios to be removed. The Php I have so far is:

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($row['cms_content']);
        $elements = array();
        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
          if($element->tagName == 'input') {
            if($element->getAttribute("type")=='radio') {
              $parent = $element->parentNode;
              if($element->hasAttribute("checked")) { // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
                $div = $dom->createElement("div");
                $div->setAttribute("class", "checked-radio");
                $div->nodeValue = 'Y';
                $parent->replaceChild($div,$element);
              } else {
                $parent->removeChild($element);
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

The html simplified is:

```
<input name="s1f1a1" type="radio" value="1" id="rdo1" class="myradio" checked><label for="rdo1" class="myradio-label"></label>
<input name="s1f1a1" type="radio" value="2" id="rdo2" class="myradio"><label for="rdo2" class="myradio-label"></label>
<input name="s1f1a1" type="radio" value="3" id="rdo3" class="myradio"><label for="rdo3" class="myradio-label"></label>
```

Comment: What's about `if($element->getAttribute("checked")) {`

Comment: Seems to works  http://codepad.org/mqna0AmK

Comment: @FieryCat Yes I tried getAttribute("checked") but didn't work. There's another  question on SO with an answer that suggests using the labels to find 'input[checked]', does that mean the 'checked' property is missing from the Php DOMDocument class? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969797/get-checked-values-from-checkboxes)

Comment: Search by pattern `input[checked]` should work, it's true  https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked

Comment: @Musa so it does work, brilliant! I found that the checked property had not actually been set in the html. Thank you!